# Anaconda, updating Numpy package, UnsatisfiableError

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

When when I try to update Numpy on Anaconda-Navigator Environments section, I get the following error:

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - keras
  - numpy ==1.13.3
Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you please show more of the output, and the exact command that you typed?

Comment: It wasn't text commands.  It was on the anaconda navigator.  I went to the environments tab and selected Numpy to update.  And then after clicking on apply in order to update, I received the above error.  That was the entire output of the error.

Comment: OK, well, what its saying is that you have the keras package installed, which doesn't support Numpy 1.13.3. You'll have to remove keras or not update Numpy